# Error CS0008 When Running Application

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0

I have an application that is installed and running fine on hundreds of client computers, except for one. This client is on Windows 7 (even though it runs perfect on Windows 7) and the application installs ok, but when you runs it he gets the following error (see below). The application was running fine for him a week ago, it has just started doing this now. I have tried a clean install, as well as reinstalling .Net 4 (which is what the application uses). Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS0008:
>   Unexpected error reading metadata from file
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0_b77a5c561934e089\System.XML.dll'
>   -- 'The given assembly name or codebase was invalid'

Comment: It is usually generated because the TEMP directory is inaccessible.  This sounds like a hard drive that's toast though.  Nothing you can do to fix that of course.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say for sure, but it smacks of the `XmlSerializer`. I'm not 100% on the 4.0 implementation, but back in the day, it would generate .cs files in a temp location, compile them, then use that code to perform serialization.

It was not uncommon to deploy code to a hardened web server and find serialization code would fail, because ASP.NET would have the rights to write to whatever the temp directory was. Can you check permissions?

Other than, how about manually delete the System.xml assembly and replace it from one of the working machines? You might need to use the command line to get there.

Neither options a sure fire bet, but worth a try.